# How to convert the columns to lowercase in join condition in Kusto Database

Tags: join, conditional-statements, case, azure-data-explorer

```
TableA
| where GuidId == "123"
| where Desc has_any ("processor")
| join kind=leftouter TableB on 
  $left.SubId == $right.SubId,  
  $left.ProductName == $right.Name,
  $left.GuidId == $right.GuidId
| distinct SubId, PriceTags, ResourceType, ProductName, Name
```

ProductName is in lower case and Name is in camel case. How to bring ProductName and Name to same case in Join condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

| extend Name=tolower(Name)

```
TableA 
| where GuidId == "123" 
| where Desc has_any ("processor") 
| join kind=leftouter (TableB | extend Name=tolower(Name)) on $left.SubId == $right.SubId, $left.ProductName==$right.Name, $left.GuidId==$right.GuidId 
|distinct SubId, PriceTags, ResourceType, ProductName, Name
```

extend Name=tolower(Name)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to 'normalize' the values before the `join`.

- Ideally you'll do this before ingestion, or at ingestion time (using an update policy).
- Given the current non-normalized values, you can do it at query time (performance would be sub-optimal):

```
TableA
| where GuidId == "123"
| where Desc has "processor"
| join kind=leftouter (
    TableB
    | extend Name = tolower(Name)
) on 
  $left.SubId == $right.SubId,  
  $left.ProductName == $right.Name,
  $left.GuidId == $right.GuidId
| distinct SubId, PriceTags, ResourceType, ProductName, Name
```